# HTML: first a text div and then a div that fills the rest of the window (NO SCROLL)

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a text at first (not fixed height) and then a div (that uses openseadragon) to fill the rest of the available space in the window. I don't want scroll bar to appear. How do I do that?

Using this code:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body >

<div >
  SOME TEXT HERE
</div>
  
<div id="openseadragon1" style="width: auto; height: auto; "></div>

<script src="openseadragon-bin-2.1.0/openseadragon.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewer = OpenSeadragon({
        id: "openseadragon1",
        prefixUrl: "openseadragon-bin-2.1.0/images/",
        tileSources: "arvore/arvore.xml"
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is what it is happening:
[image: rendering]

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle or plunker?

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you have top div with a text inside and another div that could be contain everything.
I'm going to calculate the heigh of top div, after that I calculate height of window and finally I do math: `(window)`-`(topDiv)`= `(height of another div)`

by using jQuery we can achieve that:
https://jsfiddle.net/linkers/x0wo280n/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="text">
some text
</div>
<div class="fill">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.text{
  background-color: red;
}
.fill{
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pHeight = $('.text').height();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  $('.fill').height(windowHeight - pHeight);
  alert(windowHeight);
});
```

Comment: Didn't work, fill class height is set to be window height and then body is fill class height + text class height. http://postimg.org/image/qtyarzalt/

Comment: Maybe there is something inside openseadragon container that overwrites height definition

Comment: @brgsousa did you resize the browser?
when you open the webpage first, is it okay or not ?

Comment: I didn't resize the browser after opening the page.

Comment: @brgsousa it's not possible. if you want, we can start to chat about this problem. but as I showed you in JSfiddle, it works.

Comment: I have seen it work, you are right! But didn't work for me :(